# Flutter change axis coordinates dirrections

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

Inside AnimatedContainer I draw progressBar from left to right.
Is there any way to change dirrection (mirror axis) so progress bar will start drawing from right to left ?

```
SizedBox(
  height: 20,
  child: Stack(
    children: [
      AnimatedContainer(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 100 * perc,
        color: Colors.green,
        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
      ),
      Row(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: [
          Text('text1'),
          Text('text2'),
        ],
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
```

Comment: Can you include more snippet ?

Comment: @Yeasin Sheikh updated question text

Comment: `perc` is just a double that will change the container width ?

Comment: yes that container draws progress bar under Row that has text1 and text2.

Comment: problem is that progress bar is drawn from left to right. But I want it to draw from right to left

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using   positioned widget like `Align` or `Positioned`

```dart
Align(
  alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
  child: AnimatedContainer(
    alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 100 * perc,
```

Comment: Glad to help you out, you can check more about  [Stack](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html) and [Align](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Align-class.html)